# Abort file upload by post

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use [org.apache.http.client.HttpClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.1.1/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.java#HttpClient)

to upload large files from Android to server.

```
(...)
entity.addPart(...)
entity.addPart("mediafile", new FileBody(file));
httpost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);    
(...)
```

The files are large and I need a method to cancell upload if user request, but HttpClient don´t have function to abort network operation.

How I can terminate this network operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but HttpClient don´t have function to abort network operation.

You can use `httpost.abort();`

Hope this helps!